# Adding a prefix to / renaming a list of files sequentially following the specified order

Tags: batch-rename

I have hundreds of pdf files that I need to print in the correct order (not alphabetically) but according to the Bill of Materials

File sequence look like this

```
PDS_00006_A
GAS_01945_A
PDS_00006_A
PDS_00042_A
PDS_00004_A
GLA_01132_A
PLA_00600_A
PLA_04535_A
PLA_04536_A
```

I use IrfanView to batch print in alphabetical order, so I thought about adding a sequential prefix to the files, like this

```
001_PDS_00006_A
002_GAS_01945_A
003_PDS_00006_A
...
```

How can I add that kind of prefix (using powershell, batch, or even free programs)?
Should continue on error

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do it via IrfanView, it has a batch rename feature with a Load TXT button and a name pattern settings. This little program never ceases to amaze me...